# Pass a value from jquery script into another php file with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

What i want is to get the color value from one JavaScript section into another php file which acts as a css file. I saw some example with ajax however they do not work, although the .done and .always say the data is send. So here is the script part and the color value:

```
    var jCell = '#aabbcc';


 $(document).ready(function (){
  $.ajax({
    url: "view/stylesheet/supercharge.css",
    data: {cell: jCell},
    type: "POST",
    async: false })
    .done(function(cell) { console.log("success: "+ jCell); })
    .fail(function() { console.log("error"); })
    .always(function() { console.log("complete"); })
  });
```

Here is the php file(acting as css) and it should get the value with $_post however it doesn't:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?> 

<?php 

    $menuColor = '#121212';
    $headerColor = $_POST['cell'];
    $bodyColor = '#fffaaa';

?>

#header {
    background-color: <?=$headerColor; ?>;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you expecting this to do? This returns the CSS file with the substituted variable to AJAX, but that doesn't add the stylesheet to the web page.

Comment: You say `done` fires, so as far as I can see this is working. Sounds like you're expecting something to happen other than the `console.log()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just loading the file via Ajax isn't going to activate the styles in your page. If you are expecting the css to affect your page you need to include it in your page. You need something along the lines of this. NOTE: THIS IS UNTESTED.

Add in this at the top:

```
<script id="phpcss"><?php include(path/to/phpfile); ?></script>
```

And then have this in the javascript:

```
var jCell = '#aabbcc';


$(document).ready(function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "view/stylesheet/supercharge.css",
        data: {cell: jCell},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#phpcss").html(data);
        },
        async: false })
        .done(function(cell) { console.log("success: "+ jCell); })
        .fail(function() { console.log("error"); })
        .always(function() { console.log("complete"); })
    });
```

This should take the returned css from the ajax call and put it into the head of your current file.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, this seems to work fine, but i still have a question. Do i need the CSS file at all? The point was not to display just one value but more since i want to use jpicker to add colors and change the header values.

Comment: If you're using jpicker to change a value then you need to modify it slightly, but otherwise it's fine to use and a css file is a good way to go. I've amended my answer above. That way you don't keep appending it, but modify the css each time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am not very good at jquery. Ticked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Change -

```
url: "view/stylesheet/supercharge.css",
```

TO

```
url: "view/stylesheet/supercharge.php",
```

What is your `cell` is ? is it a global variable ?

Comment: It is a css file. Here is what i did http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/

Comment: @user2468422 yet not read it..but in a glance it is also referring to     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/supercharged.php" media="screen">`

Comment: I set Elegant Method rather than the simple Method in the tutorial. "Then, instead of saving the CSS file as a *.php file, you save it as a *.css file, and you place it in a folder for CSS (in our example, ~/css/). Once you have done this, create a *.htaccess file in that folder and add the following:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css"

Answer (score 0):

try putting cell in quotes like

```
data: {'cell': jCell},
```

also this

```
view/stylesheet/supercharge.php
```

seems like it is the issue.

Comment: For the second answer http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/ it is css file but it acts as php

The first suggestion doesn't work as well.

Comment: so basically you only had the extension issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could comment! Swapnesh is correct, I just did some verifying before answering. Most servers won't parse a file with a .css extension with php. Changing your extension to .php will allow the code to execute, but the header sent indicates the response to be of type css instead of the default html. This technique is also commonly used for javascript and plain text files.

I might also add that generally speaking it's probably easier / more efficient to apply dynamic css styles with jquery directly using their [css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

```
$('cell #header').css('background-color', jCell);
```

But then again, I don't know all the reasons you're using ajax as you did not elaborate on the general idea, but take what helps and leave the rest.

EDIT: One other thing you (though more likely others reading this) may want to watch out for is short tags. Not saying you can't use them, just be aware as it states in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

> Short tags ... are only available when they are enabled
>   via the [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP
>   was configured with the --enable-short-tags option.
>
> Using short tags should be avoided when developing applications or
>   libraries that are meant for redistribution, or deployment on PHP
>   servers which are not under your control, because short tags may not
>   be supported on the target server. For portable, redistributable code,
>   be sure not to use short tags.
>
> Starting with PHP 5.4, short echo tag `<?=` is always recognized and
>   valid, regardless of the short_open_tag setting.